# How to create a rounded rectangle label in Xcode 7 and Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, rounded-corners

I am working in Xcode 7 beta 3.  I want to create a label with a rounded rectangle background.  By default, I can create a background with my color of choice but I can't round the corners.  I have tried creating an outlet for that label and then in `viewDidLoad()` I wrote this code `label.layer.cornerRadius = 10`.  I didn't get any errors but it didn't change the label in the simulator.  Does anyone know how to do this in Swift 2?

Answer (score 16):

The most simplest approach is to add this attribute to the label you want to have rounded corners.

```
layer.cornerRadius
```

[image]

And also enable **Clip Subviews** property as well.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You'll also want to clip to bounds of the label:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

> A view can optionally limit the drawing of its subviews so that any
>   parts of them outside the view are not shown. This is called **clipping**
>   and is set with the view’s `clipsToBounds` property.

So you need to add:

```
label.clipsToBounds = true
```

result (Swift 2.0 Xcode 7 iOS9):

[image: Radius of UILabel]