# How to make round corner button which supports all device in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

In my iPhone app i have profile pic button which should be round corner always.Right now if i will give corner radius some value ,button is not round cornered in iPhone 6plus.So is there any specific general way to make this work ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand that what you want to do?

Comment: Can u try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846476/how-to-create-a-rounded-rectangle-label-in-xcode-7-and-swift-2/31846658#31846658

Comment: Currently yourUIButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0; works for one mobile screen lets say iPhone 5c. I want it to be circle in all device screens....This is the problem i am unable to resolve ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If size of the  button (width, height) are same in all screen sizes then setting `cornerRadius` once should work, if its different in different screen sizes then do something like this, add button as property and then override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of view controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.button.layer.cornerRadius = self.button.bounds.size.height / 2;
}
```

Comment: or if it's not a UIVIewController and instead it's a UIView then you can just put this code into the `override func layoutSubviews()`...

Answer (score 1):

Take half of height of `bounds` and set it as radius.

```
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = self.button.bounds.size.height / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to make round corner button which supports all device in iOS

```
yourUIButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
yourUIButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
```

Also in your "m" or "h" file import: #import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h